# TypeError: this.reduce is not a function

Tags: javascript, arrays, prototype, typeerror, reduce

After adding a method to the Array prototype, some other, unrelated script breaks.

- [Opera] Unhandled Error: 'this.reduce' is not a function
- [Firefox] TypeError: this.reduce is not a function

The method itself works (`[1,2,3].xintsum()` outputs `6` as expected).

```js
// adding a function to the Array prototype
Array.prototype.xintsum = function() { return this.reduce(function(old, add) {return old + add;}, 0); };

// accessing the array in a way that worked before
$(document).ready(function (){
  var some_array = [];
  for (head_n in some_array) {
    var v = some_array[head_n];
    $('<th></th>').text(v);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: What is `this` supposed to reference? Are you sure it's an `array`?

Comment: In Chrome, I get `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLTableCellElement> has no method 'reduce'`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is happening because you are using `for..in` on an array.  You shouldn't be doing that.

When you added `Array.prototype.xintsum`, you added a `xintsum` property to *every* array.  So, what happened was, that your `for` loop iterated over that property of your array.

The value of this property is a function.  When you pass a function to `.text()`, jQuery will call it like this:

```
v.call(ele, index text);
```

It's setting `this` to the element.  And well, DOMElements don't have `.reduce` functions.

You need to loop like this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < some_array.length; i++){
    var v = some_array[i];
}
```

Comment: Or use `some_array.forEach()` ;)

Comment: Or you can use for...of from ES6. This loop addresses the problem of looping over non-element properties.

Answer (score 1):

This code:

```
var v = some_array[head_n];
$('<th></th>').text(v);
```

when it gets to `xintsum` is the same as this:

```
$('<th></th>').text(function() { 
    return this.reduce(function(old, add) {
        return old + add;
    }, 0); 
});
```

When a function is passed to `text`, the function is called once for each element contained in the jquery object which it is called on.  For each call `this` refers to that dom element.  In this case, the `th` you have created.  Therefore, the error message is letting you know that `th` has no such function.

Answer (score 0):

`v()` is being called in the context of the `<th>` element, not an array. Hence, the `<th>` doesn't have a method `reduce()`. This is because `for ... in` iterates over non-numeric properties just as much as numeric properties. I would recommend using `some_array['head'].forEach()` instead.

Comment: I believe the issue is you are using a 'for in' on an array. Because of that, you are getting the prototypes in the check.. for in... do a for loop, and your problem should be correct. You shouldn't use a 'for in' for arrays, that is for associative arrays/hashes. use "for" for an array. I *think* this is your issue.

Comment: You're welcome. BTW, console logs are often much easier than alerts, because they don't block, and usually let you inspect the object more thoroughly.